# Google Maps via Link with Region

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm currently working on a site that I want to link "Get Directions" button to Google Maps (without using the JS API). It is very important that the Sea of Japan is labeled as East Sea. This is achievable in the Google Maps JS API by setting "?region=KO" when fetching the API JS Script.

Using the example link below, is their a query string I can append to set the region as Korea. Otherwise is there another method I can use to set the region to Korea but keep the language in English.

Example of link:
https://maps.google.com/?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=Brisbane+Australia&zoom=14&directionsmode=driving

Sea Of Japan Naming Issues:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_of_Japan_naming_dispute

Thanks, Zac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Korean domain `google.co.kr` to set the region then setting the language `?hl=en` appears to give you the "East Sea" yet retain English street terminology.

East Sea https://www.google.co.kr/maps/@39.6573449,135.6637105,7z?hl=en

Sea of Japan https://www.google.com/maps/@39.6573449,135.6637105,7z

Korean Labels https://www.google.co.kr/maps/@-27.4789154,153.0226005,14z

English Labels https://www.google.co.kr/maps/@-27.4789154,153.0226005,14z?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Scuzzy,
https://maps.google.co.kr/?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=Brisbane+Australia&zoom=14&directionsmode=driving&hl=en works perfectly.